# Customize Facebook Like Box - Policy Infringement

Tags: facebook, design, terms-of-use

I'm just about to finish up a web project, and so far I've got good social media integration into the site's theme (Youtube and Twitter)...except [Facebook Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) for a not-for-profit's Facebook Page! I would very much like to show it as is without the border and the *Facebook Social Plugin* hyperlink at the bottom, and I've found out how to do so via the following links:

- http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-add-a-custom-facebook-like-box-to-your-site
- http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-your-facebook-fan-box/

Both are great resources, and allow me to accomplish my goal of total theme integration, but I came across the following Facebook policy:

> IV. Application Integration Points - 4.d. You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as the Like button or Like box plugin.

By definition to *obscure* is to conceal something, and granted that the only thing I want to conceal is the *Facebook Social Plugin* hyperlink (and perhaps change a few colors), but I've see a lot of sites that have done what I intend to do. The last thing I want is for my client's page/profile to get banned from Facebook. So I'm asking anyone who has had experience with this particular issue, if what I intend to do **does** constitute a violation of that policy, and have you heard of pages/profiles being banned from Facebook for the same reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the specific type of thing that they are trying to disallow with the policy. Consider that this link is part of their strategy to virally spread the plugin across the web. They're providing this service for your website, for free, and one of the tradeoffs of this is that you link back to them.

It's more forgivable to try change the colours or get rid of the border, although this would technically also be a violation of the policy.

I've never heard of anything being banned for this, however.

Comment: solid info. good to know! If you don't mind, I'd like to get a few more views on this subject before I choose an answer!