# How do you customize a Facebook like box?

Tags: html, css, facebook, like

I've found a few articles that allow you to customize the Facebook like box, but it's mostly just background and border color. Is there a way to customize the text color on a facebook like box? and possibly get rid of the border?

Comment: that really doesn't solve my problem/answer my question.

Comment: Agreed. @JohnConde: I think you meant [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18282/customize-facebook-like-box-policy-infringement) instead. Maddy: Basically, Facebook don't really want you customizing the box to much beyond the options they provide in their generator. It's worth noting that the question I linked is about whether customizing the box is a breach of terms(it is, technically), so while the links there do provide various tricks, Facebook might have taken action to stop them from working, or might still in the future. FYI.

Comment: Reopened! (5 more to go...)

Answer (score 2):

The only options you can use to customize the Like Box can be found on this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Other than the options they give you I don't think you are really supposed to change the code around much, as it may violate their terms of use.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to customize the like box provided by facebook's site

what you can do is implement yourself a new complete box, using the javascript API, but the features will be limited (no way to detect if logged user liked or not, for instance)

Answer (score 0):

From stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/5648870/804087

1. Get XFBML code from here:
   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/#
2. Rename fb:like-box to fb:fan
3. Upload your css file on your web-site
4. Add this params to fb tag: profile_id="ID OF YOUR PAGE"
   css="http://your-site.com/css/your-cutom-style.css?1"